# Let $f_k$, $k=1,2,\dots n$ are linearly dependent continuous functions on $(-1,1)$. Then...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $f_k$, $k=1,2,\dots n$ are linearly dependent continuous functions on $(-1,1)$. Then   $\int_0^x$ $f_k(t)dt,$ $k=1,2, \dots, n$ are linearly dependent functions on $(-1,1)$.

Would this be true or false?

See this is what I am confused about, mainly where to start, and how I can apply Linear Dependency with the problem. Maybe I truly don't understand Linear Independence/Dependence.

Comment: The functions $f_k$ are linearly independent if and only if $$c_1f_1(x)+\cdots+c_nf_k(x)=0\qquad\text{for all $x\in(-1,1)$}$$implies $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$.

Comment: Thanks for adding that comment, Dave.

Comment: What is confusing me mainly is the integral part. Or Maybe just because I see an integral I am freaking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.
Since $f_i,i=1,\dots,n$ are linear dependent, there exist $\alpha_i,i=1,\dots,n$ such that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 \neq 0 \textrm{ and} \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i(x)=0,\forall x\in(-1,1)
$$
Then integrate above equation from -1 to x we can get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \int_{-1}^x f_i(t)dt=0,\forall x\in(-1,1)
$$
It follows that $\int_{-1}^x f_i(t)dt,i=1,\dots,n$ are linear dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are linearly dependent, you know that at least one of them,say $f_1$ can be expressed in terms of the others,
$$ f_1(x)=\sum_{k=2}^n c_k\,f_k(x)\;.$$
But then 
$$ \int_0^xf_1(t)\,\mathrm{d} t=\sum_{k=2}^nc_k\,\int _0^xf_k(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\;,$$
showing that the functions $F_i(x)=\int_0^xf_i(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: You should assume $\int f_i$ be linearly independent if you want to prove by contradiction

Comment: @Focus I did not want to prove by contradiction.  Could you please read the question and answer carefully?

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks everybody.